# Port forwarding not working on Huawei B535-232 4G LTE router for ssh connection

Tags: port, router, 4g

I have a Huawei B535-232 4G LTE router with the following configuration:

- set ddns with NO-IP,
- set static ip of the server to which I want to connect remotely via SSH,
- set SSH port forwarding with: Wan port 8888 and Lan port 22 for server static ip.

I do not understand why I can not connect, the port 8888 is closed,where I am wrong ?

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here - unrelated to programming. Also, please don't repeat text, just to bypass minimum-question-length rules (I removed all that)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with B535-333 model. I managed to open ports through Virtual Servers but I can only access them from "outside" (Internet) and not locally (LAN). I get a "Connection refused" error.

It looks like a firewall/NAT problem that should be fixed with a new firmware version.